# Compare two Pandas columns of booleans with conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, boolean-logic

I have a dataframe:

```
df
     col1    col2
1    True    False
2    True    True
3    False   False
4    False   True
```

I'd like to make a new column where if the booleans are equal, it returns `False` and if they're different, it returns `True`.

Something like:

`df['col3'] = False if df['col1'] == df['Col2'] else True`

```
df
     col1    col2    col3    
1    True    False   True
2    True    True    False
3    False   False   False
4    False   True    True
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ne` not equal

```
df['New']=df.col1.ne(df.col2)
df
Out[140]: 
    col1   col2    New
1   True  False   True
2   True   True  False
3  False  False  False
4  False   True   True
```